# How show field labels in the node display even if it's empty

Tags: nodes

While showing a node, only the filled fields are rendered.
I wanted to be able to show the empty field labels, and I was looking for something like the ability to uncheck an option such as 'Hide if empty' or check a 'Display even if empty.'. Unfortunately, there are no such options.
In order to display them, I used a hook_preprocess_node:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $node = $variables['node'];
    $all_fields = $node->getFieldDefinitions();
    $node_fields = $node->getFields();
    foreach ($node_fields as $field_name => $field) {
        $value = $field->getString();
        if (str_contains($field_name, 'field_') && !$value) {
            $variables['content']['_field_layout']['content'][$field_name] =
            [
                '#theme' => 'field',
                '#title' => $label = $all_fields[$field_name]->getLabel(),
                '#field_type' => $all_fields[$field_name]->getType(),
                '#label_display' => "inline",
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

This made all the hidden fields display, but are not honouring the order set on the node display.
Is there a way to get and pass a #weight?

Comment: I think you could render those through the managed display section from content types.

Comment: Thank you @harsh-vashisht, but that's not an option using core.
It made me however look for contrib again and I did find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a contrib module that allows showing hidden fields:
https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_fields

Thank you for people chipping in that made me dig deeper ( I still can't believe how I missed it before moving to the preprocess  )

Answer (score 0):

As far as understand, most (if not all) twig files check:

```
if the field is empty
    don’t show both label or content
else
    show everything
```

I’ve came across the kind of situation you describe.
My solution was to change (appropriately) the twig files so that the label is outside the if statement.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought, however {{ content }} in the node.html.twig template is already missing the info such as labels from empty fields.

Comment: No. I'm referring to field.html.twig or some other template at the field level.

Comment: Unfortunately, those templates are only being called for fields with content. I think something in core is removing it from the rendered array. The preprocess above was an attempt to add it again...and it does, but not in the correct order.